# Keycloak not reading custom messages

Tags: keycloak

I cloned the standard Keycloak theme and have been working on some changes and customizations. As indicated in the docs, I made a copy of the message properties files, placing them in login/messages. I made a few changes to the messages. But my changes are not being used. I also added a locales setting in theme.properties and no change.

How do I get Keycloak to use my messages and not the ones in the parent base.